# \istgame: different color in payoff // action labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, game-tree, istgame

How can I

1. color code the wording "Gerichtsverfahren" red and "Verkäufer" blue?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xLfW.png
2. do the same for the payoffs - (right blue and left red)

Thank you in advance - I tried everything.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{istgame}
\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}[sloped,font=\scriptsize, scale=0.7, align=left]
\setistmathTF{0}{0}{1}


   \xtdistance{42mm}{120mm}
   \istrooto(0){0}
   
      \istb{Gerichtsverfahren, Verkäufer}[a][b]
      \istb {Gerichtsverfahren, Verkäufer)}[a][b] \endist


   \end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Thanks - I edited it. I hope its ok now.

Comment: Actually, no, it's not OK now. A Minimal Working Example should be something that can be compiled.

Comment: Start your posted code with `\documentclass{...` and finish it with `\end{document}`

Comment: -> I changed it again. I hope its ok. I am new to this.

Comment: The `istgame` package is [well documented](https://texdoc.org/pkg/istgame) with examples of the kinds of things you want to do. Have you looked there?

Comment: yes I have- I have not found anything concerning this. I would be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 2):

The [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/istgame/istgame-doc.pdf) of istgame describes various ways of coloring action labels in section 6.2.2 *Decorating action labels*, as well as ways of coloring payoffs in section 6.3.3 *Decorating payoffs*.

Some examples:

- To color the action label as well as the line, use `\istb[color]{label}`. In the MWE below this is illustrated with `\istb[red]{Schlafen}[a]{8}`
- To select a color for just the label, put the color *after* the label, together with the position specifier. Note that in this case you should write the position in full, e.g., `above` instead of `a`. This is illustrated with `\istb{Schwimmen}[above,blue]{6}`.

  - note that you can also combine these two, so to get a red line and a blue label use
    `\istb[red]{label}[blue]` (not illustrated)
- To color the payoff, put the color in an extra set of brackets in front of the position specifier. In the MWE: `\istb{Gerichtsverfahren, Verkäufer}[a]{2}[[green]below]`
- To color a part of a label, use `\textcolor{color}{text}`. In the MWE: `\istb{Gerichts\textcolor{red}{verfahren}, Verkäufer}[a]`

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{istgame}
\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}[sloped,font=\scriptsize, scale=0.7, align=left]
\setistmathTF{0}{0}{1}
   \xtdistance{42mm}{120mm}
   \istrooto(0){0}
      \istb{Gerichts\textcolor{red}{verfahren}, Verkäufer}[a]
      \istb{Gerichtsverfahren, Verkäufer}[a]{2}[[green]below]
   \endist
      \istrooto(1)(0-1){5}
         \istb[red]{Schlafen}[a]{8}
         \istb{Schwimmen}[above,blue]{6}
      \endist   
   \end{istgame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much martijn! This is very good stuff!